# Find the least value of $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function is as follows: $f(x) = 2x^2 - 6x + 8$ and the domain is less than and equal to $k$.  Find the least value of $k$ for which $f(x)$ is one to one.

I've completed the square to equal $2(x- 3/2)^2 +7/2$

The mark scheme states that the answer is $3/2$ but why isn't the answer $7/2$?  As isn't that the rule where $k$ is always the max/min point?

Comment: you mean $2(x-3/2)^2$ (x not squared)

Comment: The quadratic function is one-to-one on every branch. The top lies at $x=3/2$, so you need either left or right part. "Less than" suggests the former.

Comment: $f(1)=f(2)$, so how could it be $3.5$?

Comment: $7/2$ is the edge of the co-domain, you were confusing domain and co-domain

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square yields
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 2x^2 - 6x + 8\\
     & = 2(x^2 - 3x) + 8\\
     & = 2\left(x^2 - 3x + \frac{9}{4}\right) - \frac{9}{2} + 8\\
     & = 2\left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{7}{2}
\end{align*}
The expression 
$$f(x) = 2\left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{7}{2}$$
is the vertex form of the quadratic function.  Its graph is a parabola with vertex $(3/2, 7/2)$ that opens upwards.

[image: graph_of_quadratic_function]

The graph is symmetric with respect to the line $x = 3/2$.  Since there is more than one value of $x$ for each value of $y > 7/2$, the function $f$ is not injective (one-to-one).

If the function were injective, a horizontal line would intersect the graph at most once.  This is known as the [Horizontal Line Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test).

There are two ways to restrict the domain so that the entirety of the range is preserved.  We could take either the left half or right half of the parabola, which correspond, respectively, to the restrictions $x \leq 3/2$ and $x \geq 3/2$.

If we want the domain to be less than or equal to $k$, then we would take the left half of the parabola.

[image: quadratic_function_restricted_to_left_half_of_domain]

Notice that the function is injective when the domain is restricted to $x \leq k$ whenever $k \leq 3/2$.  If we restrict the domain so that $x \leq k$, the largest (not smallest) value of $k$ we can choose is $k = 3/2$.

On the other hand, the function is also injective when the domain when the domain is restricted to $x \geq k$ whenever $k \geq 3/2$.  If we restrict the domain to that $x \geq k$, the least value of $k$ we can choose is $k = 3/2$.

[image: quadratic_function_restricted_to_right_half_of_the_domain]

In short, the wording of the question is flawed.

By restricting the domain to $[3/2, \infty)$ or to $(-\infty, 3/2]$, we obtain an injective function that preserves the range of the original function.  This, presumably, was the actual intent of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f(x)=2(x^2 -3x+4)$

Now by completing the square we get,

$f(x)=2[(x-\frac{3}{2})^2 +\{4-(\frac{3}{2})^2\}]=2(x-\frac{3}{2})^2+ \frac{7}{2}$

As for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $a^2 \geq 0$

So, it is clear the minimum is observed at $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and equals $\frac{7}{2}$.

**Edit:**

But as, $a^2=(-a)^2\Rightarrow f$ is many-one function.

So, the only value at which $f$ behaves as a one-one function is when $a=0$
$\Rightarrow (x-\frac{3}{2})=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Observe that \begin{align*} 2\left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{2} & = 2\left(x^2 - 2 \cdot \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{9}{4}\right) + \frac{3}{2}\\ & = 2\left(x^2 - 3x + \frac{9}{4}\right) + \frac{3}{2}\\ & = 2x^2 - 6x + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\\ & = 2x^2 - 6x + \frac{12}{2}\\ & = 2x^2 - 6x + 6\end{align*}  The OP is correct about the $7/2$.